# Slow INNER JOIN with multiple ORs

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT attr1, attr2, attr3, ...
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (
    (t1.a = t2.a OR t1.b = t2.b OR t1.c = t2.c) AND
    (t1.d = t2.d OR t1.e = t2.e OR t1.f = t2.f)
```

This query has very poor performance and none of the columns on the ON clause are PKs. What would be a good alternative to improve this query?

Comment: without table stats and execution plans this will be impracticable to address.    So my guess would be `on case when t1.a = t2.a then 1
     when t1.b = t2.b then 1
     when t1.c = t2.c then 1 
     else 0 end +
case when t1.d = t2.d then 1
     when t1.e = t2.e then 1 
     when t1.f = t2.f then 1
     end = 2`

Comment: you've not shown us the structure of the tables/indices, the explain plan for the query nor (as xQbert mentions) the stats on the data cardinality/distribution. The query suggests your schema is not normalized.

Comment: Instead of obfuscating with a,b,c,..., give us a clue of what application this is -- perhaps by using the real column names.  The _may_ be a workaround that is quite different than the formulation that is giving you trouble.

Comment: Rethink your schema

Answer (score 5):

This is going to be slow.  A faster method is multiple `left join`s:

```
select t1.*, t2.?, t3.?, t4.? . . 
from t1 left join
     t2 t2a
     on t1.a = t2a.a left join
     t2 t2b
     on t1.b = t2b.b left join
     . . .
where t2a.a is not null or t2b.b is not null or t2c.c is not null or . . .
```

This can take advantage of *separate* indexes on `t2(a)`, `t2(b)`, and so on.

Note that the result set is a bit different.  Assuming at most one match per column paid, you will get all the matches for a given row on one output row.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . The `where` clause requires that there is at least one match.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a query for each join combination (9 of them) and union them together:

```
SELECT attr1, attr2, attr3, ...
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON 
    (t1.a = t2.a) AND
    (t1.d = t2.d)

UNION

SELECT attr1, attr2, attr3, ...
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON 
    (t1.a = t2.a) AND
    (t1.e = t2.e)
UNION

...

UNION

SELECT attr1, attr2, attr3, ...
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON 
    (t1.c = t2.c) AND
    (t1.f = t2.f)
```

This way you can create a composite index on each column pair.
(A, D), (A, E)...(C, F)